# Extracting and storing non-zero entries in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Could anyone help me build and correct my code which aims to only save the non-zero elements of an arbitrary square matrix and its index? Basically I need to write a script that does the same function as 'sparse' in MATLAB.

```
`%Consider a 3x3 matrix
A=[ 0 0 9 ;-1 8 0;0 -5 0 ];
n=3; %size of matrix

%initialise following arrays:
RI= zeros(n,1); %row index
CI = zeros(n,1); %column index
V = zeros(n,1); %value in the matrix
for k = 1:n %row 1 to n
    for j = 1:n %column 1 to n
      if A(k,j)~=0
        RI(k)=k;
        CI(j)=j;
        V(k,j)=A(k,j);
      end
    end 
end`
```

Comment: [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)? I'm not sure what output you're expecting.

Comment: I want the same output as if i would write sparse(A).

Comment: Then why don't you use `sparse`?

Comment: because I want to write my own script and learn how to code

Comment: MATLAB doesn't really have the built-in data structures to do this directly. For reference you can look at the bottom of the documentation page for [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html#moreabout) and there is a link to the paper detailing the data structures used and how the mathematical operations are implemented.

Comment: I think the closest you're going to get in implementing this using the built-in MATLAB types is a cell array. Of course you could build your own class to do this, but it wouldn't be as efficient as MATLAB's sparse. I'm not really sure what the end goal is here, whether you want to just build the data structure or if you want to do actual math with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`find` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to find all the non-zero elements.

So,

```
[RI, CI, V] = find(A);
%      2     1    -1
%      2     2     8
%      3     2    -5
%      1     3     9
```

**EDIT :**

I realize from your comments that your goal was to learn coding in Matlab and you might be wondering why your code didn't work as expected. So let me try to explain the issue along with an example code that is similar to yours.

```
% Given:
```

A=[ 0 0 9 ;-1 8 0;0 -5 0 ];

Firstly, instead of manually specifying the size as `n = 3`, I'd recommend using the built-in `size` function.

```
sz = size(A); 
% note that this contains 2 elements: 
%    [number of rows, number of columns]
```

Next, to initialize the arrays `RI`, `CI` and `V` we would like to know their sizes. Since we do not know the number of non-zero elements to start with, we
have two options: (1) choose a large number that is guaranteed to be equal to or greater than the number of non-zero elements, for example `prod(sz)`. (Why is that true?). (2) Do not initialize it at all and let Matlab dynamically allocate memory as required. I'd follow the second option in the code below.

```
% we'll keep a count of non-zero elements as we find them
numNZ = 0; % this will increment every time a non-zero element is found
for iCol = 1:sz(2) %column 1 to end
    for iRow = 1:sz(1) %row 1 to end
      if A(iRow,iCol)~=0
          numNZ = numNZ + 1;
          RI(numNZ) = iRow;
          CI(numNZ) = iCol;
          V(numNZ)  = A(iRow,iCol);
      end
    end 
end

disp([RI, CI, V])
%      2     1    -1
%      2     2     8
%      3     2    -5
%      1     3     9
```

Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

So I think we've established that the point of this is to learn an unfamiliar programming language.  The simplest solution is to use `sparse` itself but that gives you no insight into programming.  Nor does `find`, which can be used similarly.

Now, we could go the same route you've started using: procedural `for` and `if` over each row and each column. Could be almost any programming language, but for a few quirks of punctuation. But what you'll find, even if you do correct the mistakes (like the fact that `n` should be the number of non-zero entries, not the number of rows) is that this is a very slow way of doing numerical work in Matlab.

Here's another (still inefficient, but less so) way which will hopefully provide some insight into the "vectorized" way of doing things, which is one of the things that makes Matlab as powerful as it is:

```
function [RI, CI, V] = mysparse(A)       % first:   use functions!


[nRows, nCols] = size(A);
[allRowIndices, allColIndices] = ndgrid(1:nRows, 1:nCols)   % let's leave the semicolon off so you can see for yourself what it does.
                                                            % It's very similar to `meshgrid` which you'll see more often (it's heavily used in Matlab graphics)
                                                            % but `ndgrid` is "simpler" in that it's more in tune with the fundamental conventions of Matlab (rows, then columns)

isNonZero = A ~= 0;   % this gives you a "logical array" which is a very powerful thing: it can be used as a subscript to select elements from another array, in one shot...

RI = allRowIndices(isNonZero);  % like this
CI = allColIndices(isNonZero);  % or this
V = A(isNonZero);               % or even this

RI = RI(:);  % have to do this explicitly, because the lines above will reshape the values into a single long string under some circumstances but not others
CI = CI(:);
V = V(:);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go with a `N x 3` matrix where `N` are the number of non-zero elements in the matrix.

```
% Define a matrix A as follows:
A = randi([0 1],[4 4])
for i=1:16
   if A(i) ~= 0
      A(i) = rand;
   end
end

[row,col] = find(A);
elms = A(A~=0);  % MATLAB always works in column-major order and is consistent, 
                 % so no need to use sub2ind to access elements given by find

newSparse_A = [row col elms];
```

Output:

```
newSparse_A =

1.0000    1.0000    0.9027
2.0000    1.0000    0.9448
3.0000    1.0000    0.4909
1.0000    2.0000    0.4893
2.0000    2.0000    0.3377
4.0000    2.0000    0.9001

>> sparse(A)

ans =



   (1,1)       0.9027
   (2,1)       0.9448
   (3,1)       0.4909
   (1,2)       0.4893
   (2,2)       0.3377
   (4,2)       0.9001
```